# Can I use `last call` in a restaurant

Tags: word-choice

Can I use `last call` in a restaurant??

I can recall that my chef told me so when  I  worked as a server.

But I found that it is actually a term used in a bar.

So.. can I use it in restaurant even though it is originally from a bar??

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_call_(bar_term)) would suggest not, in general. But what you do at work is the call of the boss.

Comment: You can use it anywhere you want.  It basically means "last opportunity to place an order".  It is, however, most idiomatic in a bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, much depends on the *kind* of restaurant you work in as a front-of-house person. "Last call" is certainly a no-no if you find yourself working tables at any *Michelin* starred restaurant worth its salt, where appropriate decorum on the part of the staff is a given, just like the stratospheric check/bill for megabucks that the sucker...er...I mean customer will fork out before the restaurant turfs out the toffs on the street. You'd be far better off adopting this phrase in a small town diner on the other side of the tracks, though "last orders, please" is better known terminology, especially if you have been watching British B&W movies set in a pub *circa* 1940's and 50's.

"Last call" used to be the battle cry of the wide-eyed kid who'd make his way through the rabbit warren of passages in the bowels of a theater, knocking-up the actors as they awaited a stage entrance on cue. He's now redundant, replaced by PA-systems of one kind of another. It's just not the same. That's progress, I suppose.  (Common Knowledge)

Comment: They used to have wide-eyed kids impregnating stage actors? That sounds awfully impractical!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Silly me. I don't see it as awfully impractical, more like diabolically criminal, I'd say. Perish the thought that they were wide-eyed kids. Acne-faced adolescents more like it.